# New Folder of List not display in View

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I'm using the following code to create new list folder:

```
Folder newFolder = listCopyTo.RootFolder.Folders.Add("NewFolder");
clientContext.Load(newFolder);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

After that the new folder is exist in the list (i checked it). But it doesn't dispay in browser (view).
I found [*an article on this issue.*](http://thingsthatshouldbeeasy.blogspot.ru/2009/09/how-to-add-folder-to-sharepoint-list.html#.VVx9ztKsVg0) It says the folowing:

```
SPListItem newFolder = reportingList.Items.Add(reportingList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, “New_Folder_Name”);
//the following line will associate a list item with the newly created folder and make the folder visible in the list views
newFolder.Update();
```

But i can't to follow this way because i'm using SharePoint 2010 Client-Side Object Model.
Is there the right decision for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i resolved this issue. New folder of List must be added like new ListItem by `List.AddItem(ListItemCreationInformation parameters)` method. Just need to set `ListItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType` to `FileSystemObjectType.Folder`.

Example:

```
List listCopyTo = ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
ListItemCreationInformation newFolderInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newFolderInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
ListItem newFolder = listCopyTo.AddItem(newFolderInfo);
newFolder["Title"] = folder.Name;
newFolder.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment your post yet, so I take a shot at answering.

Have you checked in your view parameters that you are allowing the folders to be displayed ?

One other thing, in your List advanced settings, do allow folders to be created in your list ?

Comment: Hammer, thanks for reply! I haven't checked the parameter that allow the folders to be displayed and if you said it's name and it's class then i will check it at work tommorow. But i created the new folder via SharePoint web interface and it normally displayed on browser. What about EnableFolderCreation parameter of my List so i set it on "True", but it didn't help(